# DOCTRINE - DQL - Improve query - SELECT without NULL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to improve my query.

I have this table:

```
  id    lang_code   language   
    1    fr-1        french 
    2    fr-2        french     
    3    en-1        english    
    4    en-2        english    
    5    NULL       espagnol
    6    NULL       chineese
```

I did this query

```
$langues = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT c FROM AVCMediasBundle:Langue c GROUP BY c.language')
->getResult()
;
```

I have this result and it's OK for the moment

```
  id    lang_code   language   
    2    fr-2        french     
    4    en-2        english    
    5    NULL       espagnol
    6    NULL       chineese
```

But now I'm trying to improve this query. I need to do the same but without `NULL` result in `lang_code` column

The result must be like that:

```
  id    lang_code   language   
    2    fr-2        french     
    4    en-2        english
```

I tired that but some problems...

```
$langues = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT c FROM AVCMediasBundle:Langue c GROUP BY c.language , WHERE c.langCode IS NOT NULL')
    ->getResult()
    ;
```

How can I do please ? thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong order of clauses in your `DQL` (btw this would be also wrong in plain `sql`) - `GROUP BY` must go to the end of query, after `WHERE`

Try this one:

```
$langues_dispo_google_speech = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT c FROM AVCMediasBundle:Langue c WHERE c.langCode IS NOT NULL GROUP BY c.language')
    ->getResult()
    ;
```

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-syntax.htm) to see correct sql syntax